# Delete elements form a list with elements with strings and numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

I am trying to create a list `list2` removing elements from a list `list`. 
The structure of `list` is a mix of numbers and strings, for example:

```
 mata = {"mc011", "mc021"};
 matb = {"mc011", "mc021"};

list=Flatten[Table[ToString[mata[[i]] <> "-" <> matb[[j]] <> "-"<> 
    ToString[Abs[eigvaltot[i, j, 0.5]]]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], 1]
```

with the output

```
      {mc011-mc011-{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
       mc011-mc012-{1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.707107, 
        0.707107,0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107, 
        0.707107},
       mc021-mc011-{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5},
      mc021-mc021-{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5}}
```

and I need to eliminate the elements that have the first $6$ numeric values 
$=1$, in the way

```
list2={mc011-mc011-{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
       mc011-mc012-{1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.707107, 
        0.707107,0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107, 
        0.707107}}
```

Until now I was able to do it in a list without the strings using `DeleteCases`

```
DeleteCases[testb, {x_, y_, z_, i_, j_, k_, l_, n_, o_, p_, q_, r_, s_,
    t_, u_,v_} /; (z == 1 && i == 1 && j == 1 && k == 1 && l == 1 && 
    n == 1 && o != 1 && p != 1 && q != 1 && r != 1 && s != 1 && t != 1 && 
    u != 1 && v != 1)]
```

Here `testb` is a sample list that I made to try "DelateCases". Now the problem  is that when I try to include the string it does not work

```
list2=DeleteCases[list, {x_, y_, {z_, i_, j_, k_, l_, n_, o_, p_, q_, r_,
      s_, t_, u_, v_, w_, a_}} /; (z == 1 && i == 1 && j == 1 && k == 1 &&
      l == 1 && n == 1)]
```

My list `list` is huge so, I need to automatize the process. Do you know a wise way to perform this procedure?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code the `mc*` are symbols not string. You might need to post your raw data format which is more helpful.

Comment: @L.Yu Thank you, I added how the `list` was created. The first elements are part of another list with names

Comment: Please make your code self-contained so that the reader can run and debug it without needing to make up missing elements like `eigvaltot`. Doing so will greatly increase your chances of getting usable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your data are created in Mathematica, it's easy to solve your problem by not converting everything to String but keeping the List structure:

```
mata = {"mc011", "mc021"};
matb = {"mc011", "mc021"};

list = Flatten[
  Table[
    {mata[[i]], matb[[j]], Abs[eigvaltot[i, j, 0.5]]},
    {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}
  ],
1];
```

Then to filter your list as you wish by `Select`:

```
Select[list, Count[#[[3, 1 ;; 6]], 1] != 6 &]
```

Comment: Thanks is what I needed, definitely I have to lear more

Comment: You are welcome!